# Javascript clearInterval not working for timer

Tags: javascript

Why is clearInterval() not working? what am I doing wrong? I tried a bunch of things but they don't seem to work out...

```
var s = 60;
var timer = null;

function Ftimer (){
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = s--;
}

document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
    var timer = setInterval(function(){ Ftimer() }, 1000);

}

document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: Debug your code. Place a breakpoint on the `clearInterval` line. Examine the value of `timer`. Then think real hard about why it's null.

Comment: `timer` is always `null`. You assign the return value of `setInterval` to a different, local, `timer` variable.

Comment: remove `var` in your `onclick` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to you overwriting your initial `timer` variable here:

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
    // this clobbers your previous `timer` assignment
    var timer = setInterval(function(){ Ftimer() }, 1000);

}
```

So fix it by simply removing the `var` and use the outer scoped `timer` variable:

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
    // this assigns to your previous `timer`
    timer = setInterval(function(){ Ftimer() }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`var timer` makes the scope to the onclick function, not the global variable.

```
timer = setInterval(Ftimer, 1000);
```